# Event on button click with print event

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

What am I forgetting so this doesn't work:

```
<li class="item_print">
<a rel="nofollow" title="Afdrukken"  onclick="window.print();"> Print</a>
</li>
```

In GTM :

Trigger : All Click Elements => Some Clicks => Click Classes Equals

In debugmode it just doesn't fire my tag linked to this trigger, maybe it's because of the window.print() event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click on "Print" the element that is clicked is "a rel="nofollow..." and not 'li class="item_print"' as you expect.

To fix this you can change your trigger to CSS selector for example:

[image]

You can read more about CSS selecotrs here: https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/matches-css-selector-operator-in-gtm-triggers/

Comment: Found this out myself actually but fixed it by selecting on the Click Text, indeed maybe the css selector is safer!